# Pre-Greek θάλασσα "thalassa" and Turkish talaz

Tags: proto-indo-european, greek

Talaz is a word that means "wave, tornado" in Turkish dialects.  dalga means "wave" in Turkish. You can use the following two links to look up the word's attestations throughout history:

https://www.etimolojiturkce.com/kelime/dalga to
https://www.nisanyansozluk.com/?k=dalga to

When I saw the word  "thalassa"  which was defined as Pre-Greek and was not given its etymology, I did not have much foreignness. Because it continues to be used in Turkish dialects. And I think this word, defined as Pre-Greek, is one of the oldest traces of Pre- Turkic.

NOTE : talaz may be loanword from Greek, in Turkish ? I am not sure.
       I am not a Turkish   propagandist.

( sorry for English )

Comment: The meaning *storm* only came in later Greek anyway.  It seems like you're trying to be objective and not a propagandist, but the methodology you have used is essentially the one that propagandists use.  The senses, places and times just don't overlap, it's not possible without time travel.

Comment: As far as isolating IE languages, well, it's useful to note the pre-IE substrate words that survive in nearly every IE language.  For one, they are a clue to older civilisations and language families, and they help us understand how the family diverged.

Comment: You need to be careful when you write "the word", and I need to read closer, because I thought for a second you meant *thalassa* was used in Turkish dialects, not *thalassa*. Given three words and an unknown root, there are 16 possible non cyclic rooted graphs, ignoring phonetic and archeologic uncertainties and other almost necessary intermediariea: G>(T1,T2); (T1,G)>(G or T1)>T2; G>T1>T2; T1>G>T2; etc. (All rooted in x>...). That's a lot. Which variant are you implying? What does @AdamBittlingmayer suppose the *d-* comes from? Agr *th-* reflects \*dh-. I know nothing about Turkic :-(

Comment: The topic of wave+storm makes a sea-near localization attractive, though rivers can flood, too. Obviously I had to look up *deluge*. The word *wave* is also significant to *refuge-es*, *migration* as well as *storm* is to *attack*, as much as Ger *überschwappen* "to cross a threshold" (onomatopoetic?) aligns with *to swap*, or *überlaufen* "to run over" (whereas PGem \*laugo leaves me guessing; cp. *lake*). I will repeat that I am under the impression that *l-* makes for an immensly dense cluster of interleaved (see? *-leaved*!), cp e.g. *verlassen*. *sl-* fares no better.

Comment: En.wikt as of recently alleges a form *sthlabenoi* under AGr *sklabenoi* (cf. [[Slav]]), sadly without reference.

Comment: etymology of dalga : middle turkic ( xıı. century ) talkag, talkan "wave" < talka "flitter, flutter" < tal- "undulate, fluctuate".

Comment: Similar words exist all over the world, from Aromanian *tãlazi, dalgã*, over Georgian ტალღა (ṭalɣa) to Telugu అల (ala), తరంగం (taraṅgaṃ)" -- The language itself is called Telugu, roflmao -- But also, by stretch of the imagination, Sinhalese, Khmer, Armenian, Scottish-Gaellic and more (see [wave](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wave#Translation). It means *Nockenwelle* and refers to the archimedia spiral as used in water transport ... perhaps. My reasoning is that an initial glottal stop can tendentially go to k or t, and that *Quelle* "source" (cp. Yiddish *khvalye* "wave") and ... but ...

Comment: Sadly I cannot make that a *quality* answer.

Comment: Loads of marine vocabulary passed from Greek to Turkish, not the other way around. You loan terms for things that are not originally in your environment. Proto-Greek speakers in turn loaned the word from the Aegean population(s), hence Greek has a many words/nuences for a word for sea. The languages spoken in the Aegean pre-date the arrival of Turkic speakers in the area by many millenia.

Answer (score 6):

The main problem with the word 'θάλασσα' is explaining the source of the geminate -σσ-. Native Greek words and PIE words don't have geminated consonants. Further, In various Greek dialects the word appears as [θάλασσα](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B8%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%83%CE%B1#Ancient_Greek), [θάλαττα](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B8%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%84%CF%84%CE%B1) (Attic), [θάλαθθα](https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B8%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%B8%CE%B8%CE%B1) (Cretan), possibly even [δαλαγχα](https://books.google.com/books?id=mW3jn8dOrVMC&lpg=RA7-PA165&ots=2kDhN-GTLa&dq=%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%B3%CF%87%CE%B1&pg=RA7-PA165#v=onepage&q=%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%B3%CF%87%CE%B1&f=false) ("Macedonian"? according to the source). So the original source needs to have been something that could reasonably diverge into the forms /ss/, /tt/, and /ttʰ/, (and /gkʰ~ŋkʰ~nkʰ/ for that Macedonian form). See [this question on Latin Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7502/what-was-the-sibilant-in-%CE%B8%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%83%CE%B1) for a thorough discussion of the nature of this sound.

So: Any etymology for the word needs to explain not merely the first syllable θαλ- but the whole word. There is no evidence that a Turkic origin can explain the word's phonology.

Comment: Was Macedonian γχ actually `/gkʰ/`? I would have thought `/ŋkʰ/` (or `/nkʰ/` depending on your analysis).

Comment: @Draconis I was always taught that γ was `/n/` when followed by γ or χ but that was Attic.

Comment: @Mark Beadles: I would put an questionmark next to "Macedonian" for δαλαγχα. It is a pure speculation, as the word is orphan. Other than that, good answer!